# Schedule on Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

If I want to schedule a task every 5 minutes for ever and ever, should I check:

- Once + "Repeat" every 5 minutes

  - Undefinitely
- Daily + "Repeat" every 5 minutes

  - During one day
  - Undefinitely

What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is, that with once, the task will stop working when you reboot the pc, whereas with daily, it will start at the specific time and then occur every 5 minutes until the pc is shutdown.

Basically you need to define the initial trigger to a point where you want it to occur first. In your case, you should use neither of what you suggested, but instead use: at logon, and repeat that every 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks! But I need a particular time so I'll use daily. But then, what 's the difference between repeating for a day or undefinitely?

Comment: The difference is, that when you make the task repeat indefinitely it will get to a point where a current task is to run, while another scheduled task is to run (the next day) and thus, one of the two tasks will fail, given that it is already running. Also, take note there is a setting that will stop the task execution after a certain criteria, such as 3 days, or when the task failed to start 3 times.

Comment: So I assume best implementation for my needs is Daily + repeat for a day every 5 min

Comment: Yes. That would seem to be correct.